# With Bootstrap 4 I am able to fix top navbar on scrolling how can i make one more line below it fixed even in normal css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am able to make top-fixed navigation using navbar.
Below it i want to make one more heading kind of text fixed even if the page has scrolled fully which i am not able to make.

pls suggest even if it can be done using Normal CSS OR
is there any way out in Bootstrap classes.

Comment: Do you have maybe some code or can you explain it a bit more? It isn't so clear. But if you want to fix something with CSS you use `position: fixed;`.

Comment: What i am trying to ask is

Using Bootstrap 4 i have been able to create ONE Navigation Bar which remains fixed on Top at all time even if the page has scrolled fully down the page.

Now My requirement is below this Navigation Bar I want to show One Text in the center which also should remain fixed even if the page has scrolled fully down the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have added `position: fixed;` in `title-div` and set it as per your requirement.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/wuz8bk9h/3/

```css
body {
  padding-top: 104px;
}

nav.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.title-div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 56px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: aquamarine;
}

.card-section {
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="title-div">
  <h1 class="text-center">
    Title Heading
  </h1>
</div>
<section class="card-section">
  <div class="containter">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
        <div class="card card-body h-100">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card card-body h-100">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card 2</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
              </p>
              <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="">Get More</a></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card card-body h-100">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card 3</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
              </p>
              <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="">Get More</a></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card card-body h-100">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card 4</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
              </p>
              <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="">Get More</a></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card card-body h-100">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card 5</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                <br>
              </p>
              <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="">Get More</a></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot Bro... It worked exactly the way i wanted it. :)

Comment: We are glad that, our solution helped you...

Comment: I want to add logo on left side  in the same code above given by you. Pls Guide.
@Yudiz Solutions

Comment: We have added a logo on the left side, please check this link code: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/7osLqjtr/